# Read .tar.gz file in spark socket dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, tar, serversocket

Reading .tar.gz file as file stream in spark streaming is well and good enough.
but my requirement is, can we read .tar.gz file that is coming from socketserver in spark-streaming?

when is post tar file in socket like

```
nc -l 9990 < input.tar.gz
```

i can read it in spark like

```
Dataset<org.apache.spark.sql.Row> dataset = ss.readStream()
                     .option("host", "localhost")
                     .option("port", "9990")
                     .format("socket")
                     .load();
```

if i try to store the result in csv format

```
dataset
               .coalesce(1)
               .writeStream()
               .format("csv")
               .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
               .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint")
               .option("path", "hdfs://10.15.xxx.xxx:8020/user/admin/sftp/tar_output4")
               .start()
               .awaitTermination();
```

i am getting output like binary format in output csv

```
0000000:    22 ef bf bd 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ef bf bd ef   "...............
0000010:    bf bd 3b 0e ef bf bd 40 0c ef bf bd e1 ad 91 ef   ..;....@........
0000020:    bf bd 03 07 ef bf bd 18 ef bf bd 65 09 c7 a1 ef   ...........e....
0000030:    bf bd 41 01 ef bf bd 3a 7f 5c 22 ef bf bd 24 5b   ..A....:.\"...$[
0000040:    21 ef bf bd 2a ef bf bd ef bf bd 35 1e ef bf bd   !...*......5....
0000050:    ef bf bd ef bf bd 56 5b 1b 1e 6d ef bf bd ef bf   ......V[..m.....
0000060:    bd ef bf bd ca a5 21 ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd   ......!.........
0000070:    ef bf bd 0e d1 ac ef bf bd 77 47 36 0b ef bf bd   .........wG6....
0000080:    77 ef bf bd 12 ef bf bd ef bf bd ef bf bd 2d 6b   w.............-k
0000090:    37 3b ef bf bd 1f ef bf bd d7 95 3b ef bf bd 73   7;.........;...s
00000a0:    37 ef bf bd 4b 6d 59 ef bf bd 72 ef bf bd 3c ef   7...KmY...r...<.
00000b0:    bf bd 04 ef bf bd ca b3 7f 17 02 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00000c0:    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ef bf bd ef bf bd 06 59   ...............Y
00000d0:    e9 a9 85 00 28 22 0d 0a   ....("..
```

anyone please help me with this..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a TGZ codec and registered it. I use it for reading TGZ files as text/csv files.
Maybe that helps:

```
final class DecompressTgzCodec extends CompressionCodec {
  override def getDefaultExtension: String = ".tgz"

  override def createOutputStream(out: OutputStream): CompressionOutputStream = ???

  override def createOutputStream(out: OutputStream, compressor: Compressor): CompressionOutputStream = ???

  override def createCompressor(): Compressor = ???

  override def getCompressorType: Class[_ <: Compressor] = ???

  override def createInputStream(in: InputStream): CompressionInputStream = {
    new TarDecompressorStream(new TarArchiveInputStream(new GzipCompressorInputStream(in)))
  }

  override def createInputStream(in: InputStream, decompressor: Decompressor): CompressionInputStream = createInputStream(in)

  // we do not create any decompressor
  override def createDecompressor(): Decompressor = null

  // we do not create any decompressor
  override def getDecompressorType: Class[_ <: Decompressor] = null


  // see https://www.conductor.com/nightlight/how-to-build-a-speedy-custom-compression-codec-for-hadoop/
  final class TarDecompressorStream(in: TarArchiveInputStream) extends DecompressorStream(in) {
    def updateStream(): Unit = {
      // still have data in stream -> done
      if (in.available() <= 0) {
        // create stream content from following tar elements one by one
        in.getNextTarEntry
      }
    }

    override def read: Int = {
      checkStream()
      updateStream()
      in.read()
    }

    override def read(b: Array[Byte], off: Int, len: Int): Int = {
      checkStream()
      updateStream()
      in.read(b, off, len)
    }

    override def resetState(): Unit = {
    }
  }
}
...
// register the new codec:
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.set("spark.hadoop.io.compression.codecs", classOf[DecompressTgzCodec].getName)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .master(...)
      .config(conf)
      .appName("Test")
      .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Thank you @matthias. i have created my own codec for .tar.gz format. its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You reading binary files (archives) and writing output to csv files without any transformation. That's why your output csv contain binary information, it is still archive, but written to csv file. 
As far as I know there is no out-of-the-box solution for binary files for structured streaming.
Check [structured streaming programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) for all input and output modes.

Comment: Thanks @addmeaming. is there any other way in spark with socket streaming to  get binary formatted file and save it as same tar.gz file??